# Eclipse error with scala / spark project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I'm currently using the eclipse Scala IDE to develop spark streaming jobs.
It worked fine at the beginning: I created java projects with one .scala file and one Java main, added the scala nature to the project, imported the spark libs, called the scala main in the java one and all worked fine.
Now I do the exact same thing, I create other projects, and (with no code error) my project has some errors.

Those errors are the following:

```
SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'bad symbolic reference. A signature in SparkFlumeEvent.class refers to term avro in value org.apache.source which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SparkFlumeEvent.class.'. ViewLog     Unknown Scala Problem

Error in Scala compiler: bad symbolic reference. A signature in SparkFlumeEvent.class refers to term avro in value org.apache.source which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SparkFlumeEvent.class.                                     ViewLog     Unknown Scala Problem

bad symbolic reference. A signature in SparkFlumeEvent.class refers to term source in value org.apache.flume which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SparkFlumeEvent.class.                                                             ViewLog     Unknown Scala Problem

bad symbolic reference. A signature in SparkFlumeEvent.class refers to term flume in package org.apache which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SparkFlumeEvent.class.                                                                  ViewLog     Unknown Scala Problem
```

Seems like my libs in the build path are not set properly, which is weird because I did the exact same thing on other projects, using the same libraries, and everything is working fine... I tried to clean all projects, close all projects but this one, but I still get the error...

When I launch the project I have this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: viewLog/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: viewLog.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your classpath is incomplete. In particular, you're missing Apache Avro, and probably Flume. Those are dependencies of Spark itself, so in addition to Spark jars, you need to add its dependencies as well.

The simplest way would be to have an Sbt build, there's an example in the [Spark quick start guide](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html), and then export the Eclipse project using sbt-eclipse.

Comment: You were right, even if all my imports were correct in the code, it seems like a strange depency existed in the jars and after adding flure-core jar and flume-sdk jar it was ok